# Postgresql 11 extension hll not available

Tags: postgresql

```
postgres=# create extension hll;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/11/extension/hll.control": No such file or directory
postgres=#
```

Comment: How did you install Postgres? If using yum or apt, did you also install the `-contrib` module?

Comment: Did you download, build and install the `hll` extension as documented in the [readme](https://github.com/citusdata/postgresql-hll#build)